# Why is the Apple logo upside down when the lid is open on the older Apple notebooks?

Tags: macbook-pro, powerbook

Why is the Apple logo upside down when the lid is open on the older Apple notebooks?

[image: Woz using an Apple notebook with the lid open, showing an upside down Apple logo]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A former Apple employee, Joe Moreno has a blog post explaining why:

> *"We were told by the Apple design group, which takes human interface
>   issues very seriously, that they had studied the placement of the logo
>   and discovered a problem. If the Apple logo was placed such that it
>   was right side up when the lid was opened then it ended up being
>   upside down when the lid was closed, from the point of view of the
>   user."*

So when closed, it appeared right-side up from the point of view of the user. But when opened, it appeared upside down from the perspective of on-lookers. Joe Moreno states that *"Opening a laptop from the wrong end is a self-correcting problem that only lasts for a few seconds. However, viewing the upside logo is a problem that lasts indefinitely."*

All of these decisions of course went through Steve Jobs. With the release of the current Macbook product lines, Jobs reversed his decision and had the logo appear right-side up from on-looker's perspective.

Sources:

Upside Down Apple Logo - 
http://blog.joemoreno.com/2012/05/upside-down-apple-logo.html

The Upside Down Apple Logo: A Steve Jobs Mistake - 
http://www.cultofmac.com/168377/the-upside-down-apple-logo-a-steve-jobs-mistake/